# Problems using fancybox to display popup images

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

This is my code on the Site.master :

`<head runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>`

On the default.aspx page I have :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<link href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#gallery a').fancybox();
    });
</script>
<div class="gallery">
<a href="images/Books/hpcos.jpeg" rel="gallery">
<img src="images/Books/hpcos.jpeg" width="70" height="70" alt = "" />
</a>
<a href="images/Books/the_hobbit.jpeg" rel="gallery">
<img src="images/Books/the_hobbit.jpeg" width="70" height="70" alt = "" />
</a>
</div>
```

When i click on the image a page loads with just the image.Could someone please point out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose wrong selector, the current one is representing id selector whereas in your div you have defined the class. So selector should be like below :

```
$('.gallery a').fancybox();
```

This will fix your problem.